# pyserial function readline() is not working with this particular device

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to read this +-30 old device serial port information, and I was able to do it through a 3rd party application (minicom in this case) as shown below.

**minicom configuration:-**

[image]

**minicom output:-**
[image]

However what I want is to write a python (or other) code to read it in order to filter some data. When I try to read it with read() functin it works and I can retrieve the data, but when I use readline() I got some error and I can't understand why. Some code below to identify the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import serial
import os
import datetime
import binascii
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
        port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate = 1200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        #xonxoff = True,
        #rtscts = True,
        #dsrdtr = True,
        #timeout=1
)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
    
ser.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 501, in read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rawSwerialRead.py", line 22, in <module>
    data = ser.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 509, in read
    raise SerialException('read failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

I know this is not the proper way to read through serial, however anything I try with readline() will always end up on this error.

Thanks in advance,
João

Comment: I have never used the serial library but in their docs there is this warning: "Be careful when using `readline()`. Do specify a timeout when opening the serial port otherwise it could block forever if no newline character is received. Also note that `readlines()` only works with a timeout. `readlines()` depends on having a timeout and interprets that as EOF (end of file). It raises an exception if the port is not opened correctly." Could this apply to you?

Comment: Hi @Pietro thanks for you answer. That does not apply, as I've tried it with a specific timeout and the error persists.